# Gradle build keeps running

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

Gradle keeps running on IntelliJ and is frozen at "Gradle build using tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]". I have been searching for a solution since yesterday but got no luck.

Build.Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.predator.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
```

Comment: you may want to add your build.gradle file to this question

Comment: @TooManyEduardos iv added build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i was able to solve it by updating the build tools version to 24.